# Error With Taking Time Lapse Photos

Tags: python, camera

I'm trying to take a time lapse using my pi camera but whenever I try and run the code using python the following error pops up:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gpioTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    camera = picamera.PiCamera(resolution=(3264,2448))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 431, in __init__
    self._init_camera(camera_num, stereo_mode, stereo_decimate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 460, in _init_camera
    "Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' "
picamera.exc.PiCameraError: Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.
```

I have tried doing `sudo raspi-config` to enable the camera already but this has not changed anything. I have also made sure the ribbons are plugged in properly and reconnecting the sunny connector (although it's not called sunny on my camera). Any ideas on how to fix this and get the camera running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the camera can output such a resolution.
Can you try with another resolution, using one listed [here ?](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/fov.html)

For note : 2592x1944, 1920x1080,  1296x972, 1296x730 or 640x480 on V1 camera

For a V2 camera, the HD resolution is 3280 x 2464